# Output the the names of cities instead of indexes for multiple columns PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, multiple-columns

I have table "flight_route"

```
+---------+------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------+
| routeid | airplaneid |    departure_time     |      arival_time      | flight_from | destination |    destination_airport_name    |
+---------+------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------+
|       1 |          1 | "2020-08-22 18:30:00" | "2020-08-22 21:30:00" |           2 |          17 | "Airport of Aktau"             |
|       2 |          1 | "2020-09-01 10:15:00" | "2020-09-01 12:45:00" |           1 |           4 | "Lomonosov Airport"            |
|       3 |          1 | "2020-05-12 13:30:00" | "2020-05-12 14:30:00" |           3 |           2 | "Airport of Almaty"            |
|       4 |          2 | "2020-05-13 05:45:00" | "2020-05-13 07:15:00" |          17 |           5 | "Airport of Peter"             |
|       5 |          2 | "2019-08-22 18:30:00" | "2019-08-22 21:30:00" |           9 |          12 | "Airport of Paris"             |
|       6 |          2 | "2020-12-31 23:30:00" | "2021-01-01 04:00:00" |           7 |           4 | "Airport of Lomonosov Airport" |
|       7 |          3 | "2021-01-15 14:30:00" | "2021-01-15 16:30:00" |           4 |           1 | "NN Airport"                   |
|       8 |          3 | "2020-04-29 20:00:00" | "2020-04-29 23:00:00" |           9 |          17 | "Airport of Aktau"             |
|       9 |          4 | "2020-05-07 15:30:00" | "2020-05-07 17:00:00" |           1 |           2 | "Airport of Almaty"            |
|      10 |          4 | "2020-07-12 16:35:00" | "2020-07-12 19:00:00" |          15 |           2 | "Airport of Almaty"            |
|      11 |          5 | "2020-10-06 10:15:00" | "2020-10-06 11:00:00" |           8 |           7 | "Airport of Tokyo"             |
|      12 |          5 | "2020-02-11 14:30:00" | "2020-02-11 15:45:00" |           3 |           1 | "NN Airport"                   |
|      13 |          5 | "2020-01-30 18:30:00" | "2020-01-30 21:45:00" |           2 |          17 | "Airport of Aktau"             |
|      14 |          5 | "2020-04-22 03:15:00" | "2020-04-22 05:15:00" |          13 |          14 | "Airport of Nice"              |
+---------+------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------+
```

with "flight_from" and "destination" columns referring to "city_list" table.

```
 +--------+--------------------+
| cityid |     city_name      |
+--------+--------------------+
|      1 | "Astana"           |
|      2 | "Almaty"           |
|      3 | "Shymkent"         |
|      4 | "Moscow"           |
|      5 | "Saint-Petersburg" |
|      6 | "Novosibisk"       |
|      7 | "Tokyo"            |
|      8 | "Kyoto"            |
|      9 | "Frankfurt"        |
|     10 | "Berlin"           |
|     11 | "Hamburg"          |
|     12 | "Paris"            |
|     13 | "Lyon"             |
|     14 | "Nice"             |
|     15 | "Mumbai"           |
|     16 | "Bangalore"        |
|     17 | "Aktau"            |
+--------+--------------------+
```

I wanted to know how to print the names of cities instead of their indexes on columns "flight_from" and "destination"

edit1: added table in text format

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: It seems that you need simple INNER JOIN here. For example `SELECT routes.*, cities.city_name AS from_city FROM routes INNER JOIN cities ON cities.id = flight_from`

Comment: @dfens I tried to do double join for each column `SELECT c_f.city_name AS from_city, c_f.city_name AS to_city FROM flight_route JOIN city_list as c_f ON c_f.cityID = flight_from JOIN city_list as c_t ON c_t.cityID = destination`, but it just prints 'from_city' twice under different column names.

Comment: You selected c_f city as to city instead of c_t

Comment: @dfens oh, my bad, now it works, much appreciated!